# How to relate collections in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Using SQLite, I had a table of products, one category and one subcategory.
The subcategory had FK of the category, and the product had FK of subcategory.
But since Cloud Firestore is a non-relational database, Id like to understand how it works
the relationship of collections or documents.

Comment: Some possible approaches are presented in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jm66TSlVtcc

Answer (score 1):

Any relationships between documents and collections is purely one that you express in code.  Unlike many SQL databases, you can't force referential integrity between items.  You can create reference type fields that point to other documents, but those documents don't have to exist.  You can also simply store document IDs as string within other related documents.  It's entirely flexible and up to you to decide what's best for your specific case.

Comment: Could you please give me an example if you have one?
Or some well explained link? I have tried in my code several ways but I can not result.
I'm using Ionic